# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict' when creating a Token in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I facing issues in authentication. I am trying to create a Token but getting the error "*int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'*". Below is a snapshot of my code.

```
*Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
>>> Token.objects.get_or_create(user={'password': '123456', 'username': 'username'})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 127, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 405, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 325, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1309, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1337, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1199, in build_filter
    lookups, value)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1756, in get_lookup_constraint
    lookup_class(target.get_col(alias, source), val), AND)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 139, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 727, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 985, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'*
```

Tried my best to solve this without asking. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't user be a `User` object? Why are you passing a dictionary?

Comment: Thanks!!! Sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create) doesn't work the way you've shown, that is, it doesn't span relationships. You must have an existing user to create a token:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='username') # Or create one
>>> Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authtoken/models.py#L21 for the `Token` model code.

You'll have to pass a `User` object, and not just a combination of username/password.

Create the user `myuser` first, then do a `Token.objects.get_or_create(myuser)`.